# facebook sdk php, display all fields as default

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

is there any way to display all fields as default on each request, without specifying each field?

currently doing this enumerating the fields for Ad Account - Ads:

```
$fields = array(
'id',
'adset_id',

'date_format',
'creative',
'name',
'status',
'tracking_specs',
'display_sequence',
'execution_options',
'adlabels',
'bid_amount',
'redownload'
    );
$fields_comma = implode(",", $fields);

$account_id = 'act_'.$account_id;
    $config = array();
    $config['app_id'] = FB_APP_ID;
    $config['app_secret'] = FB_APP_SECRET;

    $fb = new Facebook($config);
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken(FB_USER_TOKEN_X);
    $request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$account_id.'/ads?fields='.$fields_comma);

    $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
```

Comment: No, there is not. They introduced the necessity to specify fields to reduce the amount of data that gets send – and if they offered an easy “workaround”, then imagine how many developers would chose the lazy option of just continuing to request “all there is, because I can’t be bothered with being specific.”